# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am new to command handler I am trying to execute commands for different js file

but I get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

this is my main.js

```
// Import the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
// Create an instance of a Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const prefix = "$"

/**
 * The ready event is vital, it means that only _after_ this will your bot start reacting to information
 * received from Discord
 */
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});
 
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


  if(command === 'pingg'){
    client.commands.get('pingg').execute(message, args);
  }




  if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

  try {
      client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
  }
});
  
client.login('censored');

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
  if(err) console.error(error)
  let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")
  if (jsfiles.length <= 0) {
    return console.log("No commands to log in FOLDER NAME")
  }
  console.log(`Loading ${jsfiles.length} commands from FOLDER NAME...`)
  jsfiles.forEach((f,i) => {
    let props = require(`./commands/${f}`)
    console.log(`${i + 1}: ${f} loaded!`)
    client.commands.set(f, props)
  })
})
```

my ping.js

```
module.exports = {
    name : 'pingg',
    description : 'Test',
    
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('pongg')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands are registered in `client.commands` collection in the bot application lifecycle after the client is ready.
This is because `client.login` is invoked before it.

You can use `commandFiles` to load the commands from their modules. This was already performed sychronously so you have some guarantee on the order.
Also do that before the `client.login` statement.

Another issue is that the command module is named `ping.js` and as such your current implementation registers ping command to `client.command` collection.
However, you are resolving `pingg` command from the collection which returns an `undefined`

```
commandFiles.forEach(file => {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
});

client.login('censored');

//...
```

Comment: You're having that error because of the mismatch in the command name and the name of the module. The one is `pingg` and the later is `ping.js`. 
You can register the `command` object in exported in the command module to the value of `name` field in the command object.

Comment: ty so much it wokrs